# Style not updating in component - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main component, and when I pass down a prop to another component, it doesn't update the style. The `display` is still `none`, whereas it's meant to update to `block` since I have changed the prop to `true`. What might be wrong?

```
class Apps extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Don't do this!
    this.state = { showing: true, Login: false, Signup: false, Members: false };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="container"
          style={{ display: this.state.showing ? "block" : "none" }}
        >
          <div>A Single Page web application made with react</div>
        </div>
        <LoginComponent view={this.state.Login} />
        <div className="buttons">
          <a href="" ref="login" onClick={this.Login_onclick.bind(this)}>
            {this.state.Login ? "back" : "Login"}
          </a>
          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  Login_onclick(e) {
    this.setState({ Login: !this.state.Login });
    e.preventDefault(); //alert(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ showing: !this.state.showing });
    // this.setState({ref: !ref});
  }
}
```

**Login Component**

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: this.props.view
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="login"
        style={{ display: this.state.show ? "block" : "none" }}
      >
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <br />
        Username: <input type="text" ref="username" />
        <br />
        Password <input type="password" ref="password" />
        <button value="Login">Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are setting `this.state = { show: this.props.view }` when the component is created. Changing the `view` prop after that will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `this.state = { show: this.props.view };` when the component is created. Changing the `view` prop after that will have no effect.

There is no need for you to set `show` in your `state` if your want it to update when the prop updates.

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="login" style={{ display: (this.props.view ? 'block' : 'none') }}>
        <h3>Login</h3><br/>
        Username: <input type="text" ref="username"/><br/>
        Password <input type="password" ref="password"/>
        <button value="Login" >Login</button>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}
```